# Nativescript Applying androidElevation to a stacklayout

Tags: nativescript

Nativescript docs say androidElevation is a valid property for the stacklayout, but is not displayed when added in my ng project. The same elevation applied to a label works fine. Is there some additional property that needs to be added?

```
<StackLayout margin="10" androidElevation="12">
  <Label text="sample1"></Label>
  <Label text="sample2"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try setting a background color too on StackLayout? Can you share some code?

Comment: I've added some some sample code. There is no background color. I tried adding one and it did not create the elevation.

Comment: It seems to create elevation when a background color is set. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: You're right. I had set the background color in my actual code not the sample I put up and, probably because my actual code is far more complex, it didn't work. When I add a background color to the above sample, the elevation does show. Thanks for the help @Manoj!

Answer (score 1):

`androidElevation` works only when you set a background color on the view.

```
<StackLayout margin="10" androidElevation="12" style="background-color: red;">
  <Label text="sample1"></Label>
  <Label text="sample2"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I found why it didn't work in my actual code. I had the Stacklayout enclosed in a Scrollview. When I moved the Scrollview inside the Stacklayout and added the background color the elevation appeared. Thanks again.